# Delayed redux dispatch call speeds up UI update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a simple block stacking game in ReactJs, Redux and TS. I want to move the top line in the stack from left to right and back, infinitely, until Space or Enter key is hit. First when the UI loads it works fine but soon after it starts to speed up the UI updates with inconsistent updates. Like this...

[Game Preview](https://media.giphy.com/media/aKULUX14v6e3a9zjSH/giphy.gif)

[Inconsistent UI updates log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ0ZG.png)

I want to update the position by 1 step every render after 200ms of delay.

I'm trying to do it like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (play) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            moveStackLine(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), direction);
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

moveStackLine function:

```
const moveStackLine = useCallback((_data: GameData, directionCopy: 'left' | 'right') => {
    console.log('_data1', _data);
    let _direction = directionCopy;
    const lastIndexData = _data[_data.length - 1];
    if (_direction === 'right' && lastIndexData[1] < gameWidth) {
        lastIndexData[0] += 1;
        lastIndexData[1] += 1;
    }
    if (_direction === 'left' && lastIndexData[0] > 0) {
        lastIndexData[0] -= 1;
        lastIndexData[1] -= 1;
    }

    if (lastIndexData[1] === gameWidth - 1) {
        _direction = 'left';
    } else if (lastIndexData[0] === 0) {
        _direction = 'right';
    }
    _data.splice(_data.length - 1, 1, lastIndexData);
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.CHANGE_ACTIVE_LINE_START_END_POS, payload: _data });

    if (_direction !== directionCopy) {
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.CHANGE_DIRECTION, payload: _direction });
    }
}, [dispatch, gameWidth]);
```

Above function changes the start and end position of the data Array inside my rootState.

initialState:

```
export const gameState: InitialGameState = {
  currentLine: 0,
  gameWidth: 16,
  gameHeight: 20,
  direction: 'right',
  play: true,
  data: [[2, 5], [0, 3], [4, 7]],
}
```

Each array inside data array represents a line and the start and end position of the line.

My render logic looks like this.

```
const renderLine = (startEndIndex: Array<number>) => {
    const columns = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < gameWidth; j++) {
        columns.push(
            <div className={cx(styles.ball, { [styles.active]: j >= startEndIndex[0] && j <= startEndIndex[1] })}></div>
        );
    }
    return columns;
}

const renderGame = () => {
    const lines = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < gameHeight; i++) {
        lines.push(
            <div id={i.toString()} className={styles.line}>
                {renderLine(data[i] || [-1, -1])}
            </div>
        )
    }
    return lines;
}

return (
    <>
        <div className={styles.gameContainer}>
            {renderGame()}
        </div>
    </>
)
```

Comment: Does data represent positions on the board?

Comment: @van yes, each array is a line. and number inside those array represent line's start and end position on the board.

Answer (score 1):

You are directly modifying `_data` here, which I assume is also the object that you retrieved from the Redux store. Which would mean you are modifying the redux store outside of a reducer.

Things like this would cause all kinds of side effects.

And not only are you doing this, you are also modifying `lastIndexData` - which is also a *reference to an object in the store* - here, again, you are modifying the store directly instead of updating it with a reducer.

Try

```js
const moveStackLine = useCallback((data: GameData, directionCopy: 'left' | 'right') => {
// .concat will create a new array reference that you can (flatly) modify as you want
 const _data = data.concat()
```

```js
// .concat will create a new array reference that you can (flatly) modify as you want
lastIndexData = _data[_data.length - 1].concat();
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. But I figured it out. It was because of the direction change dispatch call. Thank you for your help anyway!!

Comment: Even if it didn't, those were clear bugs - keep an eye out for accidental state mutations in the future and maybe take a look at the official Redux Toolkit, which would warn you about these.